# How do I make a bottom fixed position menu in HTML?

Tags: html, css, layout, menu

I want to create a box-menu on the very bottom of the browser window.

- It should stay at the bottom when the content doesn't fill up the entire screen
- When the content overflows it should only be at the bottom when you scroll down (i.e. you can't see it if you don't scroll).

How do I do this?

Comment: What is a "box menu"? Consider linking to an example. Can't you just place it at the end of the rest of your page content, (with any appropriate css, if required) so that it just ends up ad the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is called a "sticky footer", and there are a couple of methods. I suggest you have a look at these sites:

- http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/
- http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Zoom in/out on each site in order to see how this appears when the content reaches the footer or does not.

Both methods fall short on one thing: They require you to know the height of the footer - but I have not seen any better solutions with only CSS.